# Xamarin Inspector Extension for VS 2017

Tags: xamarin

I have installed Xamarin Inspector for Windows but I could not see any button on Visual Studio 2017. Is there any VS extenstion for Xamarin Inspector for Visual Studio 2017. This link has a solution for VS 2015.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36509

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Enterprise?

Comment: No. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio `Enterprise` includes

- Bytecode Hiding
- Live App Inspection
- Profiler
- Test Recorder IDE

Community and Professional editions do not.

https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio